# Credential sign in problem in next-auth. Credential authorization returns status 401

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to deploy my Next.js project on vercel. My login works in development but I face problems in Production while signing in with credentials. The status returned is 401.

I think that the authorize function is returning null thats why I get the status 401. I am not using an adapter to the MongoDB database. Could that be the problem?

Here is the authorize code:

```
      async authorize(credentials): Promise<UserAuthentication | null> {
      await connectToDatabase()
      // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
      console.log('authorize function is running')
      // Check if the user exists in the database
      const user = await UserModel.findOne({
        username: credentials?.username,
        // password: credentials?.password,
      })
      if (user && credentials?.password) {
        console.log(credentials?.password)

        const checkPassword = await compare(
          credentials?.password,
          user.password
        )
        //Incorrect password - send response
        if (!checkPassword) {
          console.log('Password doesnt match')
          return null
        }
        console.log('checkPassword:', checkPassword)
      }
      //Else send success response
      console.log('user', user)

      if (!user) {
        console.log('NO USER')
        return null
      }
      // If all checks pass, return the authenticated user object
      return user
    },
  }),
  GoogleProvider({
    clientId: googleClientId,
    clientSecret: googleClientSecret,
  }),
  
],
  })
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the vercel deployment url to google authorised urls for your project.

Comment: Google provider works fine. Its the credentials provider that are causing the error